# How can I add items to Chrome's cache without the user visiting the page?

Tags: javascript, image, caching, google-chrome

This is a weird one. I'm working on an app that allows for offline reading of saved pages, and it saves the HTML to a WebSQL database. Of course, this doesn't allow for images, non-embedded stylesheets, or anything of that nature - all that's saved is the base HTML file. That's really all I need, since the app is focused on article reading, except that I would like image support.

The problem is, I have no way of easily saving images. I suppose I could loop through the HTML and download the src of every img tag, and save it in a blob type in the database, but then I'd have no way of putting that back in the article when it's pulled up for later reading - I can't exactly say `<img data="sql query">`, as nice as that would be. If HTML5 File API support wasn't minimal at best on Chrome (my target platform for this), I'd use that, but there's 0 tutorials on it, so I don't even know where/if I could begin.

So, I've decided to go with caching the images. Now, if the user actually visits the page to save later, this is easy. But, sometimes, the user may not have visited the page. Is there a way for me to basically add each image to the Chrome cache when the HTML is downloaded?

(and, I guess, if not, can anyone think of alternative ways to do this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can exactly say

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: That is called a base64 image, to do that in Chrome, you can make use of HTML5 Canvas. You load the image in the canvas and then you call .toDataUrl().

Comment: Well, I can't use .toDataUrl() or canvas because it's not an image in the document - it's image data from XMLHttpRequest (a cross-site request possible in Chrome extensions/apps). I've yet to find a Javascript Base 64 encoder library that actually works correctly with the binary data.